# Microsoft CRM: How to reopen an opportunity by code? SetStateRequest deprecated, Update not working

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, deprecated, setstate

How do I reopen a closed (won or lost) opportunity via C# code in Dynamics CRM? `SetStateRequest` is deprecated (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setstaterequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9)), and when I try to do the same via an `Update` I get this error:

> Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:anyType' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'Microsoft.Crm.Common.ObjectModel:ActivityState'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'ActivityState' and namespace 'Microsoft.Crm.Common.ObjectModel'.

The code for this is:

```cs
Entity updateTarget = new Entity("opportunity", opportunityId);
updateTarget["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue(0); // 0 = Open
updateTarget["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(1); // 1 = In Progress
orgSvc.Update(updateTarget); // Raises exception
```

Executing a REST PATCH request to set statecode and statuscode produces the same error.

I temporarely deactivated all plugins running on opportunities to make sure that those aren't the cause for this error.

This seems to be an exception for opportunities. Other records may be closed and opened using `Update` without any issues.

I tested this on CRM 8.2 and 9.1.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, try it without `OptionSetValue`, just as `updateTarget["statecode"] = 0;`

Comment: This produces the error "State code is invalid or state code is valid but status code is invalid for a specified state code.".

Comment: OK, so try adding an additional statement: `updateTarget["statuscode"] = 1` which is the code for "in progress"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying this on another tenant where it worked I came to the conclusion that there has to be some component responsible for this error. Lo and behold, there is a third party plugin registered on RetrieveMultiple of any Entity. Upon deactivating this plugin the Update works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you could so.

1. Using c#

   For c# is just updating statecode to 0
2. Using REST (WEBAPI)

For Webapi just using PATCH method and set statecode to 0

Now how do you call it via Webapi. Here is the sample Code From front end Side to call it. You can easily replicate this using Postman and see how this helps.

```
var entity = {};
entity.statecode = 0;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PATCH", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/opportunities(8CA20837-715F-E911-A83A-000D3A3852A3)", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

Comment: This produces the error "The opportunity is already closed." Which makes sense. Why whould WinOpportunity or LoseOpportunity reopen the record? Have you tried this approach? Keep in mind that I'm trying to reopen an opportunity. I'm not trying to close it.

Comment: You are right, I misread your question. I have updated my answer and I just tried using webapi in my System. It did opened closed opportunity.